# Installing rEFInd on Dual Boot Windows 10 Machine

Tags: windows, bootloader, refind

I have two Windows 10 instances on my laptop.

When I check the Boot Entries with VisualBCD the first entry for Windows A is this:

[image: this]

The one for Windows B is this:

[image: this]

Now I added 2 entries to the *refind.conf*

```
    menuentry "Work Station" {
        icon \EFI\refind\themes\icons\os_win.png    
        volume 4:
        loader \Windows\system32\winload.efi
    }
    menuentry "Music Station" {
        icon \EFI\refind\themes\icons\os_unknown.png    
        volume 5:
        loader \Windows\system32\winload.efi
    }
```

When I reboot I first get into the rEFInd bootloader. When I select one of those two entries I get some message that the *winload.efi* could not be located...

I can only get back into one of those two Windows instances by selecting the automatically found entry, getting back into the Windows bootloader and then selecting either Windows A or B.

How can I boot directly into one of the two Windows instances without first getting into the Windows bootloader? I just cant figure it out. I already used C or D and the GUID's of the volumes in the volume part of the menuentries...

Comment: Why are you using `winload.efi`? The Windows bootmanager is `EFI/Microsoft/bootmgfw.efi`.  If you are trying to use something in `system32` you would need an EFI NTFS driver - do you have one? It is supplied by default with rEFInd but even so idk if you can use it to skip the bootmanager.  You could try copying `EFI/Microsoft/bootmgfw.efi` to `EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi` and setting each separately in `bcdedit`.

Comment: I want to boot directly to Windows A or B through rEFInd. I don't want to use the Windows bootmanager at all anymore...

Comment: I completely understand and I do this using rEFInd.  I do it by calling *bootmgfw.efi* in different EFI partitions on different disks.  You then set each Windows instance to just boot immediately rather than give a choice of OS.  You can *try* doing this on one EFI partition by duplicating the bootmanager from `EFI/Microsoft` to `EFI/BOOT` but IDK if it would work.  I don't think you can just skip `bootmgfw.efi` but I'll test it.

Comment: Ok - but how could i edit that second EFI to only boot into Windows B? 

Also how would i create a second EFI Partition like you have and how would i point that to only Windows B? I never really did anything like this so i sadly have no clue of how to do all of this. I really appreciate your help lx07. Also thanks for editing the post to correctly show the images (=

Comment: You don't directly edit anything in EFI - you use `bcdedit` or `msconfig` commands in Windows.  These update a file called *BCD* in `EFI/Microsoft/Boot`.  Then *bootmgfw.efi* will look at the *BCD* file in it's own directory (I *think* only in it's own directory) and if it has only one boot option (Windows B say) it will boot it direct.  Certainly if you have 2 EFI partitions it is OK - I'm not sure if you can simulate this by duplicating directories within one EFI partition.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how i can get 2 efi partitions and set them up separately with win A and win B and then how to point refind to it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102645/discussion-between-lx07-and-kazoooka).

Comment: Here is an interesting article tutorial, which I found very helpful in my quest. makes refind the default bootloader and keeps windows from changing it. Installing refind from Windows 10 https://schdck.github.io/Installing-refind-from-Windows-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to have 2 EFI partitions.

I use rEFInd as bootmanager - this is screenshot:

[image: rEFInd]

As you can see the selected OS is the middle one and text says `Boot Microsoft EFI Boot from ESP` This will then start Windows on Disk2 partition 4.  Were I to select the left hand one it would say `Boot Microsoft EFI Boot from EFI` and start Windows on Disk0 partition 3 (see partitions below).

These are picked up automatically using *refind.conf* like this (the manual stanza for Windows 10 is disabled as it always showed it on the right hand side that I didn't like):

```
timeout 5
use_nvram false

# UI
hideui hints,arrows,badges
banner themes/colourful/10-6.png
selection_big   themes/colourful/selection_big.png
selection_small themes/colourful/selection_small.png
showtools shell,csr_rotate,apple_recovery,shutdown

# mac stuff
csr_values 10,77
spoof_osx_version 10.9
enable_and_lock_vmx true

# search locations
scanfor internal,external,biosexternal,optical,manual
dont_scan_volumes "RECOVERY","FAT VOLUME","Windows"
#dont_scan_dirs +,EFI:/EFI/Boot,EFI:/EFI/GRUB,C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B:/EFI/Microsoft
dont_scan_dirs +,EFI:/EFI/Boot,EFI:/EFI/GRUB

menuentry "Windows 10" {
    icon \EFI\refind\myicons\os_win_old.png
    loader \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
    disabled
}
```

These are my physical partitions:

```
A1398% diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data Windows                 68.2 GB    disk0s3
   4:           Windows Recovery                         1.1 GB     disk0s4
   5:       Microsoft Basic Data Data                    107.4 GB   disk0s5
   6:           Linux Filesystem                         12.9 GB    disk0s6
   7:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         53.7 GB    disk0s7

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI ESP                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS SamsungHFS              76.3 GB    disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         50.0 GB    disk2s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data SamsungNTFS             85.2 GB    disk2s4
   5:       Microsoft Basic Data exFAT                   26.8 GB    disk2s5
   6:           Linux Filesystem                         10.7 GB    disk2s6
```

I have 2 disks and `ESP` is the volumes name of *one* of the EFI partitions.  The volume names are not important - I just named the internal one `EFI` and the external one `ESP` so I could remember the difference.

Both ESP and EFI volumes contain a directory `EFI/Microsoft/Boot` and both contain the Microsoft bootloader *bootmgrfw.efi* and within the same directory the BCD file.

rEFInd calls the chosen *bootmgrfw.efi* which can see NTFS (so there is no need for the rEFInd NTFS driver) and this looks at the BCD file in its own directory which defines which Windows bootloader to run.

[image: EFI partition]

Each instance of Windows BCD has only one entry (it's own) and so selecting the relevant icon in rEFInd boots the separate Windows instance direct without the Windows bootloader asking anything.

This you set on the boot tab in `msconfig` in Windows where *in each instance of Windows* you define only the one boot entry.

It may be possible to duplicate this behavior with only one EFI partition by copying the whole of `EFI/Microsoft/Boot` to `EFI/Boot` or creating a second EFI partition on the same disk but I haven't tried this as I only want second Windows instance to be available when the external drive is connected.

Comment: WOW - you're the man lx07! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you've figured out your install. I wanted to post my findings here for future seekers of the truth.

@lx07's answer is great. My situation was slightly different to theirs (and from what I can tell, similar to yours) in that I did *not* have a second Windows `EFI` partition.

rEFInd needs a separate `EFI` partition for *each* operating system you want listed. To make a new `EFI` partition for your second Windows install, we need to use `bcdboot` on Windows:

With admin rights on Windows, run `diskpart` (you can also do this using installation/recovery media). We will use this program to manage the partitions on our disk.

If you have multiple disks:

```
list disk
select disk #
```

where `#` is the number of the disk you're adding the `EFI` partition to.

Then:

```
list partition
select partition #
```

where `#` is the number of the partition where Windows is installed. **Remember this should be the Windows install without its own `EFI` partition.** In my case this was the Windows I installed second. You should be able to figure out which Windows doesn't have an `EFI` partition by looking at how the partitions are organised.

We can then shrink this partition, and make a new `EFI` partition:

```
shrink desired = 100
create partition efi size = 100
format quick fs = fat32
```

Assign it the drive letter `S`, and make a note of the drive letter of the Windows partition we're making the `EFI` for:

```
select partition #
assign letter = S
list partition
list volume
exit
```

where `#` is the partition number of our new `EFI` partition.

We can then use `bcdboot` to make the `EFI`.

`bcdboot X:\windows /s S: /f UEFI`

where `X` is the drive letter of our Windows install.

You should now be able to boot directly into your second install of Windows by selecting the right `EFI` option in the boot menu. rEFInd should automatically look for installs on load, and should now have two bootable Windows options. You might need to change around the boot order and stuff like that.

To get rid of Windows Boot Manager from appearing on your first Windows install, on Windows go to `System > About > Advanced system settings`. Go to the `Startup and Recovery` settings and set your first Windows install to default. Untick the first tickbox `Time to display list of operating systems` and it should now skip the boot manager.

There's probably a better way to do this (by remaking the `EFI` of our first Windows install?) but this works for me and I have no desire to mess with boot settings unless absolutely needed.